# does using print statement instead of logging statement have any performance implication in flutter/dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have seen many using `print()` statements in flutter app to view messages.

1. Does it have any performance implications?
2. Isn't it better to use a logger instead?

Comment: The main difference between using just `print` and a logger is that most logging frameworks supports different categories and priority of messages and can filter based on this. So you will in most situations end up with less log in your production logs since you are properly not going to have verbose debug information here.

Comment: Print is a quick solution for printing to console. Logger is more pro solution where you can specify what kind of messages require less or more attention. In any case _screen logger_ will use `print`.